# Test harness for python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, python-2.7

I am coding in python where I need to run servers. For this I open each terminal and start each server. Finally I have a client that contacts servers to get the information.

Now I need to test this and develop a test harness. So how can I open a terminal (from there connect to cluster) and then run the code.

Help me with any python code to run my code.

Ex:

```
$ssh 10.0.0.1:2000
[10.0.0.1.2000~]$python server.py 10.0.0.1:3000
..
..
..
..
```

Now the server.py code should run

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple shell script instead?

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh 10.0.0.1:2000 python server.py 10.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: Pardon me, I was confusing it with `bash`; you don't need `-c` with `ssh`.

Comment: Should that be `ssh 10.0.0.1:2000 'python server.py 10.0.0.1:3000'`?

Comment: Just tried; either works. Anything after the first non-option arg becomes arguments to the command. This is not very well documented.